# JS vs JSON for config in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

What should I use for configuration ?

Some module like KrakenJS highly supports configuration through JSON and the blog https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-best-practices-part-2/ say JS should be preferred over JSON.

Can you tell me how they differ and what's the best way to manage them ?

Comment: As it's written, the opinion part of your question stands too much. Could you rephrase it (the differences between formats and the way to handle that are on topic).

Comment: I voted to reopen. Too many developers make the wrong choice because they didn't think about the differences (or didn't even consider js as a configuration format) so I think the comparison should be made.

Comment: Please use js. 1) You might have to import some packages, which is not possible in JSON. Also there are nice lib out there like github.com/indexzero/nconf . 2) And another reason is, if you want to validate a condition if/else, you wont be able to do this either. Simple example would be `if domain== localhost or production`

Comment: @Trying2Learn, thats true.  even i prefer JS conf. but by seeing module like kraken which is based on JSON config,  i wonder what is the advantage of using JSON.

Comment: `This JSON file contains key value pairs that are loaded at runtime. The advantage of this is that all your application configuration is in a single, well-known place; and you can swap it out without having to touch a single line of code. This config file is also where you can define middleware and specify it’s load-order.   A common scenario is that development environments have slightly different parameters than production. Kraken allows you to define a second file config/development.json with alternate values, and control using  NODE_ENV `source: http://krakenjs.com/index.html#documentation

Comment: @Trying2Learn A config file is a config file. A production environment should have a different config file than a development one, so there is no need for a conditional structure. If you put the config as part of the code and copy the same file to every server, then that's not a config file, it's a program file.

Answer (score 30):

You should accept both.

**JavaScript** configuration files have many advantages:

1. programmable of course, which allows for interesting extensions and for generated parts
2. lighter and less awkward to type (less quotes, trailing commas, etc.)
3. lets you have **comments** (a big limitation of JSON, [here's why they're needed](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/config-default.js))
4. more value types (`NaN` & infinites, regular expressions for example)

In this case the JS file exports a plain JS object, similar to what you would have had as a result of a parsed JSON file.

**JSON** is more socially accepted, because JS isn't often thought as a configuration format. Letting people use JSON will prevent a *"JS is for logic"* sterile debate and there's no problem if people are happy with it.

**Accepting both formats:**

[Here's](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/main.js#L6) how reading the JS/JSON configuration can be done:

```
try {
    config = require('./config.js');
} catch(err) {
    if (err.code==='MODULE_NOT_FOUND') {
        config = require('./config.json');
    } else {
        console.error('config.js loading failed');
        throw err;
    }
}
```

In any case, the JSON configuration file can be turned to a JS one by just prefixing it with

```
module.exports =
```

so nobody's locked in that format.

Comment: Note sure, who down voted it. up voting it as 3rd point is really needed.

Comment: only problem is that if you start saving your configs in json then you  can follow a standard from an open source project and end up following a set format. Otherwise with `config.js` files, every programmer puts their own spin on it. and you end up having to figure out someones config.js file.

Comment: @Sumobob By a configuration in JS I mean a configuration exporting a plain object (similar to what you would have had in JSON).

Comment: @DenysSéguret yup I understood, just meant there is less examples of that than `config.json` files so theres less of a standard format, programmers write their own crazy logic in the config.js haha

Comment: @Sumobob A way to avoid that, IMO, is to ask people to copy and modify a default file. Of course they can get out of the way but they're guided.

Comment: I always felt that JS is more flexible for config than JSON. I can write logic, conditions etc. But I am consistently seeing many projects supporting JSON for conf.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg My impression is that people using JSON for configuration didn't think enough about the JS alternative and what that would bring. The ability to describe the configuration, to comment some value out, are game changing

Comment: May be better in terms of flexibility, but that's not everything in this life. If you are following the MVC approach I'd say data should be kept as data (JSON) and the application logic as a programming language (JS). Having the config file in JS is like having Models and Controllers mixed in one file. Keeping them separately makes sense and usually keeps your code a bit tidier.

Comment: @MarcCompte I disagree. The JS file might very well be similar to the JSON file (look at [my example](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/config-default.js)) but it offers you comments and more value types.

Comment: @DenysSéguret It's not a matter of how similar it can be, but how dissimilar it may become. Again, I'm not talking about specific examples, but from a theoretical point of view. Data is data (JSON) and logic is logic (JS). You can mix them, of course, but that's it, you are mixing them.

Comment: You're making up that dichotomy. Data is data. You may have different ways to produce it, be it a JSON file or a file whose name doesn't end with "ON". What matters are convenience, conventions.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: Conventions _do_ often conflict with convenience, though.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I'm not making up anything. And it is not a dichotomy, it's a three tier approach: Models (data), Views (presentation) and Controllers (logic). Just because you don't like it or you don't know it, it doesn't mean you have to go about accusing others of inventing things. Convenience and conventions are two different things. Your argument favors convenience, mine favors conventions.

Comment: @MarcCompte I may have been unclear (or excessive). What I mean is that configuration has nothing to see with MVC (or any of the many many many existing patterns you can use to describe an architecture). It's just some data for your application and you must provide a convenient ways for your user (including any system starting your application) to produce it in a manageable way **outside** of the application. Saying it shouldn't involve logic is mixing concerns. Your application shouldn't force the configuration producers to use some specific solution. I favor convenience *and* API.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Precisely. Adding control structures doesn't help your users understand the config file. No control structures = easier to edit. And comments can be in a separate file. So I still fail to see the advantages of JS to store the config info. It's not such a big deal to do what you say, I know, I even do it sometimes. But if the question is "what's best", for me JSON is best for config files, no discussion. Everything else is a workaround.